# gvim view script output in realtime in quickfix window

Tags: windows, vim, gvim

I'm using gvim in a windows environment and have some custom scripts that I use to build with. Currently, all of my build output redirected to a new tab, but I have to wait for my build to finish before anything is displayed (this is my biggest problem right now).

I would like to be able to view the output in real-time, as it is being generated -- ideally in a quickfix window.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Only if it were *nix, you could use `tmux` or `screen`, but I don't know if there are any equivalents in windows.

Comment: I would imagine then that I could use cygwin's gnu screen and accomplish what I want. <thunder and lightning> BWA HA HA! </thunder and lightning>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Vim lacks the multi-process/multi-threading capabilities needed for such a feature. There are a few "async" plugins that try to work around that limitation though, like Tim Pope's [dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) or Marc Weber's [vim-addon-async](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-async).